# App doesn't show up on device

Tags: android

So I'm learning android programming and everything is going well, until I came to this problem.
I'm using android studio and transfer my app to my phone, this has worked well until now. The app start automatically and works fine, but when I go back to the home screen on my phone the app is not there, it's not saved on my phone. The problems is the same when using the emulator.

anyone know this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need a line in the android manifest that tells us that the app will appear in the launcher.

Check this link out :
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-developers/csokbhepUG0

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, add this to your main activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

You probably already have the `MAIN` action on the activity, you just need to add the category  `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` so that it shows up on the launcher.